# Subresource Integrity when using @import

Tags: css

What is the syntax to include subresource integrity when using @import?

```
@import url(//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css);
```

Besically how do I include the subresource integrity and crossorigin parameters when using `@import` like above?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: SRI is a browser-thing, CSS at-rules (like @import) are a css-thing.

> What is the syntax to include subresource integrity when using @import?

From what I can tell, there is nothing in the current CSS spec (CSS3 drafted as of writing this) - where usage of @import is defined - that details usage of SRI for css.

> Besically how do I include the subresource integrity and crossorigin parameters when using @import like above?

Those parameters define how the browser fetches the resource and interprets its legitimacy. This happens before the resource is implemented (js, css, etc.).

---

External Resources:

- CSS3 Spec draft (specific to at-rule usage): https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-3/#at-ruledef-import
- MDN page on @import usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import
- MDN page detailing SRI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity