# How to Link to external style sheet in CSS

Tags: html, css

**Edited, because the link to the "already answered solution" does not help.**
 See addition at the end of this question

### Original question

I have two links to external style sheets in all my HTML pages. Therefore I want to put them in one external style sheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Html Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" (etc)
...
```

This works fine. `Index.Html` shows some nice icons:

```
<p>
  <i class="fas fa-fish"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-frog"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-user-ninja vanished"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</p>
```

However, I have to add the link to font-awesome to all my HTML pages.
I thought it would be a good Idea to move the reference to font awesome to `MyStyles.css`. What is the correct syntax?

Incorrect MyStyles.Css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"  (etc)

body {background-color: lightblue;}
h1 {color: yellow; margin-left: 20px;}
... (etc)
```

What is the correct syntax?

### Addition

This question seems to be [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-in-another) In the answer it says:

```
@import url("base.css");
```

I like it that the asnwer is so easy. All I have to do was to move the original link to the CSS.

The original (functioning) text in `index.html` was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Note: after the reference to the imported CSS file are some parameters!**

Several tries in `mystyles.css, similar to the answered question, alas none of them worked:

(1) Only import the css file. But where to put the extra parameters?

```
@import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css");
```

(2) Put everything inside the url statement:

```
@import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous")
```

(3) Put the parameters after the closing bracket:

```
@import url ("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css") integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

(4) The original import statement in the references answer tries to put it into double quotes, one of the answers here suggests to put it in single quotes:

```
@import url ('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css') integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

(5) [W3Schools suggests not to use brackets](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp) at all:

```
@import url "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

**So: anybody knows the correct syntax?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `@import url` like

```
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css');
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I should put the extra parameters after `http...all.css`. So where to put the parts `integrity="sha384-..." crossorigin = "anonymous"`

Comment: That doesn't work with @import. See [Subresource Integrity when using @import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300118/subresource-integrity-when-using-import)