# Is there a way to link a stylesheet in CSS instead of each HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use font awesome icons on my pages. Is there a way to link the FA stylesheet in CSS so that I do not have to add it to the head of every single one of my html pages? (I have around 45 at the moment.)

This is the code I am referencing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I have researched on the internet possible solutions and I think using the @import url action should do the trick but I don't know how to go about doing so that the 'integrity' and 'crossorigin' stay in the code.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300118/subresource-integrity-when-using-import which unfortunately doesn't have an upvotable answer yet... and thus can't be used as a target

Answer (score 0):

Can you use PHP? Move your header code to header.php and just include the header for each page;

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```